Problems with rounding datetime
I am having problems rounding the datetime columns in my dataset. I need to round a dataset to the nearest half an hour so I can use it with another dataset that have been already rounded.
I have tried the following:
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(tidyr)

# Create a datetime column
df$datetime <- with(df, ymd_hm(paste(year, month, day, hour, minute, sep = "-")))

# Round to nearest 0:30:00
df$rounded_datetime <-as.POSIXlt(round(as.double(df$datetime)/(30*60))*(30*60),origin=(as.POSIXlt('1970-01-01')))

the problem is that I get these values:

Why my datetime and rounded time don't match?

Probably related to your timezone. See this post for details. The default timezone for the ymd_hm function is "UTC".
# Create a datetime column
df$datetime <- with(df, 
   ymd_hm(paste(year, month, day, hour, minute, sep = "-"), 
   tz=""))  # Add this.

# Round to nearest 0:30:00
df$rounded_datetime <- as.POSIXlt(round(as.double(df$datetime)/(30*60))*(30*60),
   origin=(as.POSIXlt('1970-01-01')))

df
    year month day hour minute            datetime    rounded_datetime
  1 2019     4  25    8     19 2019-04-25 08:19:00 2019-04-25 08:30:00
  2 2019     4  25    8     49 2019-04-25 08:49:00 2019-04-25 09:00:00
  3 2019     4  25    9     19 2019-04-25 09:19:00 2019-04-25 09:30:00
  4 2019     4  25    9     48 2019-04-25 09:48:00 2019-04-25 10:00:00
  5 2019     4  25   10     18 2019-04-25 10:18:00 2019-04-25 10:30:00


df <- structure(list(year = c(2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019), month = c(4, 
4, 4, 4, 4), day = c(25, 25, 25, 25, 25), hour = c(8, 8, 9, 9, 
10), minute = c(19, 49, 19, 48, 18), datetime = structure(c(1556151540, 
1556153340, 1556155140, 1556156880, 1556158680), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = ""), rounded_datetime = structure(list(sec = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0), min = c(30L, 0L, 30L, 0L, 30L), hour = c(8L, 9L, 
9L, 10L, 10L), mday = c(25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L), mon = c(3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), year = c(119L, 119L, 119L, 119L, 119L), wday = c(4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), yday = c(114L, 114L, 114L, 114L, 114L), isdst = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), zone = c("HKT", "HKT", "HKT", "HKT", "HKT"), 
    gmtoff = c(28800L, 28800L, 28800L, 28800L, 28800L)), class = c("POSIXlt", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = c("", "HKT", "HKST"), balanced = TRUE)), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = "data.frame")


Thanks, That worked. I tried something similar but added tz="UTC" thinking that maybe I needed to convert it to UTC not knowing it was the default tz

You use the lubridate package once (for ymd_hm() ), you could also use  the handy lubridate::round_date() with unit = "30 mins" : df$rounded2 = round_date(df$datetime, unit ="30 mins")
